# In fabric js, how to get the original image source from image object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In fabric js, I am trying to get the original source of an image, when I use the getElement() and getSrc() methods it shows the correct output, but after applying some image filters the same methods
return the new image src (encoded image data) not the original image source.how can I get the original image source after applying the image filters.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the source of original image by accessing the fabric.object methods.

```
// Assuming your image object is selected. 
var object = canvas.getActiveObject(); 

var originalSource = object._originalElement.currentSrc;
```

will give you the original image source.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getSrc()` method:

```
var someUrlOrDataUrl = image.getSrc();
```

Docs: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#getSrc